# How do I remove Ubuntu on my computer?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I want to remove my Ubuntu on my computer.

When I go to Windows, I decide to format the disk but I got this:

[image]

Can someone teach me how to remove Ubuntu on my computer using Windows 7

Thank you in advance!

I also got this:

http://s1186.photobucket.com/albums/z373/a26776500/?action=view&current=Image1-2.png

Comment: It doesn't look like you have Ubuntu.  You cannot format your boot drive.

Comment: Yeah, those are NTFS partitions. Ubuntu's partitions are usually ext4 and never NTFS.

Comment: @tijyba I believe Disk Managemente tool of Windows is able to see, and erase linux partitions.

Comment: I have already install ubuntu so if I doesn't have Ubuntu installe    d so why I can not used those partitions?

Comment: Did you install via wubi?

Comment: no,I install via live cd

Comment: I'm sorry, but where is the Ubuntu partition?? Did you install Ubuntu via wubi (the windows installer for ubuntu)??

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english. As you can see the empty partition(which is 14.75 and 117MB) is the Ubuntu partition but I am not sure,and I can not find those partition is my computer so I think it is about ubuntu.

Comment: I have removed GRUB before . and I am not install via wubi

Comment: @tijybba: Not exactly true. While Windows Explorer cannot see Ubuntu partitions the Disk Management program can. It just can't do anything useful with them (except perhaps delete them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu is probably installed in the 14.75 GB OEM Partition shown in your image since the others are all NTFS (which means Windows) or much too small.

I think you are trying to delete the 117Mb System partition (which is probably diagnostics software for your PC).

While you may be able to delete the Ubuntu partition, doing so may render your PC unbootable. If your PC boots via `grub` in the Ubuntu partition (which is likely), deleting this partition **will** stop the PC from booting up at all as `grub` won't find it's boot files, so won't be able to boot either Ubuntu or Windows!

If you are confident about it, then instructions for replacing `grub`'s bootloader by the Windows bootloader can be found here. http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/03/10/restore-the-windows-bootloader-to-mbr-after-dual-booting-with-linux/

However, since it's only using 14.75Gb of your approx 400Gb disk, I'd recommend just forgetting about it until such time as you are doing a reinstall of Windows (when you can just reformat the whole disk).

Comment: Thank you for answering! Thank you very much! I have  delete the grub so it's would not be a problem and I can likely booting in windows 7 via test. So you suggest me just forgetting about it but anyway did have any method do get it removed? when I right click it just show ''help''

Comment: If you've already got rid of `grub` then Windows should be able to delete the 14.75Gb partition holding Ubuntu. As mentioned, the 117Mb `system` partition is probably diagnostics and should be left alone; it's NTFS so is probably related to Windows anyway.

Comment: sorry,I don't really underestand that.But this action just restore the bootloader to windows,not to be delete the 14.75Gb partition holding.

Comment: The point is that having restored the windows bootloader (and got rid of grub) windows should be able to delete the 14.75GB partition and then you can use the space for something else.

Answer (score 0):

- If you installed Ubuntu inside Windows (via Wubi), follow [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/#How_do_I_uninstall_Wubi.3F).
- Else, you can uninstall any OS (Ubuntu, Windows...) via this little tool: [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller)

[image]

Comment: He doesn't have Ubuntu installed.  See the image

Comment: So how the heck he wants to uninstall ubuntu when ubuntu is not installed?

Comment: Possibly installed via wubi.